# How can I unzip a file programmatically without writing to the disk using Pentaho?

Tags: java, zip, pentaho

I am working on a project that requires me to extract data from a ZIP file without writing the unzipped files to the disk. I am using Pentaho for my project and would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this using Pentaho's APIs.

I have tried using the Unzip step in Pentaho's ETL tool, but this writes the unzipped files to the disk, which is not acceptable for my use case.

Is there a way to unzip a file in memory using Pentaho's APIs? If so, can someone please provide an example of how to do this? I am relatively new to Pentaho and would appreciate any guidance or examples that can be provided. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the step `Modified JavaScript value` with a little help of java code:

```js
var filePath = "D:\\file.zip";
var bytes = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Paths.get(filePath));
var zis = new java.util.zip.ZipInputStream(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

function extractContentFile(zis){
    var baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    var buffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(1024).array();
    var len;
    while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return new java.lang.String(baos.toByteArray());        
}

var zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
while (zipEntry != null) {
    var entryName = zipEntry.getName();
    if(entryName.equals("posts.json")){
        var content = extractContentFile(zis);      
    }
    zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
}
```

In my case the file `posts.json` is a text file, so you can use the variable `content` in the steps ahead like a String. Remember to map the variables you want to use in the `Fields` section:

[image]